# Camera turns 180 degrees in the y direction then mirror image?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xna

i am designing a 3d game in xna. Once my spaceship moves 180 degrees in the Y driection( not x or z), then i get a mirror image.. i dont know why this happens but this happens wether this is in an environment or wether the camera follows the spaceship or not. the whole environment changes view and becomes a mirror image of the previous view. Does anyone know why?

Edit: well What kind of info do you need? there is the camera matrices , and the spaceship matrices although it seems that everything is changing , and the controls of course.

Comment: How does the ship move? Are you playing with the matrices at all? Do you get any errors? Please post as much (applicable) info as you can, it may help us spot the error easier. :)

Comment: Please post some source code, how your classes look and where you actually change matrices. I suspect you're somehow changing projection matrix?

Answer (score 0):

it *sounds* like you might be gimbal locked ... lots of info online (sorry for the brief answer)
[http://www.bing.com/search?setmkt=en-US&q=XNA+gimbal+lock](http://www.bing.com/search?setmkt=en-US&q=XNA%20gimbal%20lock)